# Declaring defaulted assignment operator as constexpr: which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

Consider

```
struct A1 {
    constexpr A1& operator=(const A1&) = default;
    ~A1() {}
};
struct A2 {
    constexpr A2& operator=(const A2&) = default;
    ~A2() = default;
};
struct A3 {
    ~A3() = default;
    constexpr A3& operator=(const A3&) = default;
};
```

GCC and MSVC accept all three structs. Clang rejects `A1` and `A2` (but accepts `A3`), with the following error message:

> ```
> <source>:2:5: error: defaulted definition of copy assignment operator is not constexpr
>     constexpr A1& operator=(const A1&) = default;
>     ^
> <source>:6:5: error: defaulted definition of copy assignment operator is not constexpr
>     constexpr A2& operator=(const A2&) = default;
>     ^
> 2 errors generated.
> ```

([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ZBUrMJ))

Which compiler is correct, and why?

Comment: Good question. The following is only a guess... We know that ``constexpr`` in functions doesn't mean ``const``. It means whether or not that function can be computed at compile time. The silently created copy assignment operator is not preceded by a ``constexpr``. This means that the ``constexpr`` you have is an overload to the silently created one. The overload however cannot be defaulted, which explains the error. Check out the following 3 code examples: 1) (clang) https://rextester.com/WLGFD87794, 2) (gcc) https://rextester.com/RMWQ86797, 3) (vc++) https://rextester.com/MXIHQ50551 .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think all three compilers are wrong.

[[dcl.fct.def.default]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default) says:

> An explicitly-defaulted function that is not defined as deleted may be declared `constexpr` or `consteval` only if it would have been implicitly declared as `constexpr`. If a function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, it is implicitly considered to be `constexpr` if the implicit declaration would be.

When is the copy assignment operator implicitly declared `constexpr`? [[class.copy.assign]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#10):

> The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator is constexpr if
>
> - X is a literal type, and
> - [...]

Where a literal type is, from [[basic.types]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#types-10):

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> - [...]
> - a possibly cv-qualified class type that has all of the following properties:
>
>   - it has a trivial destructor,
>   - [...]

`A1` doesn't have a trivial destructor, so its implicit copy assignment operator isn't `constexpr`. Hence that copy assignment operator is ill-formed (gcc and msvc bug to accept).

The other two are fine, and it's a clang bug to reject `A2`.

---

Note the last bit of [dcl.fct.def.default] that I quoted. You don't actually have to add `constexpr` if you're explicitly defaulting. It would be implicitly `constexpr` where that is possible.

Comment: Adding `constexpr` **should** give you an error if it isn't `constexpr`, which is something that could be quite useful.

Answer (score 8):

The C++17 standard states:

> **15.8.2 Copy/move assignment operator [[class.copy.assign]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.assign)**
>   ...
>
> [10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.assign#10) A copy/move assignment operator for a class X that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used (6.2) (e.g., when it is selected by overload resolution to assign to an object of its class type) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration. **The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator is `constexpr` if**
>   (10.1) — `X` is a literal type, and
>   (10.2) — the assignment operator selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is a `constexpr` function, and
>   (10.3) — for each non-static data member of `X` that is of class type (or array thereof), the assignment operator selected to copy/move that member is a `constexpr` function.

The copy-assignment operator satisfies the above requirements in two of the cases. In the first case, we have a non-literal type because of the non-trivial destructor.

So I believe Clang is wrong to reject the code in the second case.

There is a bug filed with Clang titled: [Defaulted destructor prevents using constexpr on defaulted copy/move-operator](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25689) which shows the same symptoms as the code in the OP.

The comments from the bug report state:

> When defaulted destructor is commented out (i.e. not user declared), then errors cease to exist.

and

> The problem also goes away if you declare the destructor before the copy assignment operator.

This is true of the code in the question as well.

As @YSC points out, another relevant quote here is:[[dcl.fct.def.default]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#3) which states:

> An explicitly-defaulted function that is not defined as deleted may be declared `constexpr` or `consteval` only if it would have been implicitly declared as `constexpr`. If a function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, it is implicitly considered to be `constexpr` if the implicit declaration would be.

Comment: related: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#3 and http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#10 (already quoted)

Comment: May I translate this into: Changing the order of destructor and copy assignment definition (like OP did for `struct A2` and `struct A3`) shouldn't have any effect (for compiling the code without error)?